# H2 data.sql script is delayed till the first requests are executed

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, h2

I have a Spring Boot 3 application with an in-memory H2 database.

Here is my application.yaml:

```
spring:

 jpa:
  show-sql: true
  defer-datasource-initialization: true
  properties:
   hibernate:
    globally_quoted_identifiers: true
   database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
   hibernate:
    ddl-auto: create-drop

 datasource:
  url: jdbc:h2:mem:ss
  driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  username: sa
  password: 1234

 h2:
  console.enabled: true

server:
 port: 9000
```

I have a data.sql script to generate users for my database:

```
INSERT INTO "user_entity" ("id", "name", "password", "roles")
VALUES (1, 'Oleg', '$2a$10$dNs0mv9.Eec/63hUKnfjsev01FjPxJ/XqufRBpJ0B7NBX58gzMDhW', 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER');

INSERT INTO "user_entity" ("id", "name", "password", "roles")
VALUES (2, 'User', '$2a$10$a.EjXU1y/tiykrOePDVxGOQMLWzbXD/qTQ.0PT2vfUsYg/ZJvB9EG', 'ROLE_USER');
```

Here is my User entity:

```
package com.ss.demo.domain.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UserEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
    private String password;
    private String roles;
}
```

So I have a constraint on field "name" in UserEntity. After the start of the application, everything worked fine: tables were autogenerated by Hibernate and data was inserted by script. But when I want to register another user using controller, I have the following issue on the first attempt:

```
could not execute statement [Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.user_entity(id) ( /* key:1 */ 1, 'Oleg', '$2a$10$dNs0mv9.Eec/63hUKnfjsev01FjPxJ/XqufRBpJ0B7NBX58gzMDhW', 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER')"; SQL statement:
insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default) [23505-214]] [insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default)]; SQL [insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default)]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.user_entity(id) ( /* key:1 */ 1, 'Oleg', '$2a$10$dNs0mv9.Eec/63hUKnfjsev01FjPxJ/XqufRBpJ0B7NBX58gzMDhW', 'ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER')"; SQL statement:
insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default) [23505-214]]
```

and for the second attempt:

```
could not execute statement [Unique index or primary key violation: "PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.user_entity(id) ( /* key:2 */ 2, 'User', '$2a$10$a.EjXU1y/tiykrOePDVxGOQMLWzbXD/qTQ.0PT2vfUsYg/ZJvB9EG', 'ROLE_USER')"; SQL statement:
insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default) [23505-214]] [insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default)]; SQL [insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default)]; constraint ["PRIMARY KEY ON PUBLIC.user_entity(id) ( /* key:2 */ 2, 'User', '$2a$10$a.EjXU1y/tiykrOePDVxGOQMLWzbXD/qTQ.0PT2vfUsYg/ZJvB9EG', 'ROLE_USER')"; SQL statement:
insert into "user_entity" ("name","password","roles","id") values (?,?,?,default) [23505-214]]
```

Finally, for the third attempt, everything worked fine. It looks like the queries from the data.sql script were executed during the first two attempts, despite the fact that they were already executed during startup. Does anyone have a clue what could be the cause of this problem?

I've tried to google the problem, but it seems like I cannot formulate